# How can I improve speed of code that generates an orbit plot?

Tags: differential-equations

I am attempting to generate an orbit for the "time 2 Pi map" of a forced damped pendulum. The example comes from page 57 in the Chaos text by Alligood,Sauer and Yorke, see Figure 2.7. The code generates the plot, however I have not been able to increase the number of points beyond 50,000.  The program just continues to run and I have to abort execution.  From the example in the text the authors use one half million points and that is what I would like to use if possible.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol[{a_, b_}] := 
NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t] + 0.05 \[Theta]'[t] + Sin[\[Theta][t]] == 
2.5 Sin[t], \[Theta][0] == a, \[Theta]'[0] == b}, \[Theta], {t, 0,2 Pi}]

f[{u_, v_}] := {Mod[\[Theta][2 Pi], 2 Pi], \[Theta]'[2 Pi]} /.sol[{u, v}] // Flatten

list = NestList[f, {-1, 2}, 4000]; 
(* this uses 4000 points I would like to increase this value *)
\
ListPlot[list]
```

Comment: Thank You. This was just the information I was seeking. Now I will take some time to digest it.  Thanks for the quick and thorough response!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problems that I can see are that

- `NDSolve` has to rewrite the equation system and determine which solver to use at every step.
- `NDSolve` has to interpolate the solution over all values, but you only need the last value.
- You evaluate `θ'[2π]`, but you only ask `NDSolve` for `θ`, not its derivative. So at each step you are actually taking the derivative of the interpolated solution.

In order to tackle these issues we have to delve into [the advanced aspects of `NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#2125957807). The link explains what I am doing, and I will merely do it (ask if there are any questions). This is my code:

```
eqns = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{θ''[t] + 0.05 θ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] == 2.5 Sin[t],
     θ[0] == -1, θ'[0] == 2}, {θ, θ'}, t];
step[{u_, v_}, eqns_] := Module[{neweqns, solved},
  neweqns = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[eqns, {θ[0] == u, θ'[0] == v}];
  NDSolve`Iterate[neweqns, 2 Pi];
  {Mod[#, 2 Pi], #2} & @@ NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[neweqns, "Forward"][[{1, 2}, 2]]
  ]
list = NestList[step[#, eqns] &, {-1, 2}, 4000];
ListPlot[list]
```

This code took 2.67 seconds to evaluate on my computer whereas your original solution took 42.95 seconds to evaluate, so this new solution is approximately sixteen times faster.

With half a million points the plot looks like this:

[image: Plot for half a million points.]